# convert echo expression to ?> <?php

Tags: php

What would be the right syntax to convert this expression

```
echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name_title" value="'.$value5.'" placeholder="Write your First Name">';
```

in the format

```
?>

    <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name_title" value= ????????????? 

<?php
```

On the second format I can not find a way to set the `value = $value5`

Comment: `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($value5) ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php
$var1="Xxx"
?>

<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name_title" value= "<?php echo $var1; ?>"/>
```